# I'm trying to create an onListItemClick even for a customized adapter. The array of items is found in res/values folder

Tags: android

This is the Java class that displays the array items alongside their images. I want to create an `OnListItemClick` such that when the user clicks on an item it goes to a particular activity:

```
public class MenuActivity  extends ListActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ;
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu) ;

        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.optionID , getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_options))) ;
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) ;
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, parent , false) ;

            String[] items  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_options) ;

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1) ;
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.optionID) ;

            tv.setText(items[position]) ;

            if(items[position].equals("Administration")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.admin) ;
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Regions and Divisions")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.regions) ;
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Monuments")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.monuments) ;
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Historical Places")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.historical) ;
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Resources")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.resources) ;
            }

            return row;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `getListView().setOnItemClickListener()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can do like this.

```
 ListView lv = getListView();
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    //Do your stuf here

                }
            });
```

or simply set the onclick listener of **row** in your adapter just above where you returning it.

Mark as up, if it works for you.

Comment: Please enlighten me!!. When i do 
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, R.id.optionID , getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_options)) ;
  setListAdapter(adapter) ;

   setOnListItemClick(adapter);

it sees SetOnListItemClick(adapter); as an error. why is it so??

Comment: It just underlines it with a red color, which means an error as per eclipse.

Comment: Hover your mouse pointer on that red line, it will show you the error.